# Punctuating reporting speech

Tags: punctuation, reported-speech

How do I punctuate a sentence like this:

> May he stay in school and become a doctor wished his parents while we
> his friends wished may he return home soon and join the army along with us.

This is from a poetry

Comment: The sentence needs to be rewritten rather than punctuated.

Comment: @RonaldSole It needs proper punctuation, especially quotations, to read meaningful. (it is from a poem) It would be appreciable if you could contribute towards that.

Comment: If it's from a written poem, it should be punctuated as written by the author.

Answer (score 2):

> 'May he stay in school and become a doctor,' wished his parents while we, his friends, wished, '[M]ay he return home soon and join the army along with us.'

I have suggested adding two sets of quotation marks, adding one pair of bracketting commas for the appositive, and beginning the second quote with a capital letter as it is a complete sentence.

Here are two guides:

1

> After a Verb of Saying

> Capitalize the first letter if the quotation appears after a verb of saying, regardless of the case used in the source–but flag any alterations you make.

> A quotation that follows a verb of saying (e.g., writes, says, states, exclaims) and is run in to your text is introduced with a comma and begins with a capital letter.

https://style.mla.org/capitalizing-start-of-quotation/

2

> [T]he quotation inside the quote marks begins with a capital letter if it is a complete sentence, but not otherwise.

http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/quotes/marks

EDIT

Here is a 3rd guide, on using commas in direct speech.

https://www.lexico.com/grammar/comma#grammar/comma#commas_in_direct_speech

> You also need to use a comma at the end of a piece of direct speech, if the speech comes before the information about who is speaking. In this case, the comma goes inside the quotation mark:

> 'I don’t agree,’ I replied.

Further information is shown.

> If the piece of direct speech comes after the information about who is speaking, you need to use a comma to introduce the direct speech. The comma comes before the first quotation mark.

Steve replied, ‘No problem.’

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why we need to add a comma next to "doctor" inside the first quote?